Partial Fscanf result
I have to following code which attempts to parse a date string:
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := "24-02"
    r := bytes.NewReader([]byte(s))
    var year uint
    var month uint
    _, err := fmt.Fscanf(r, "%04d-%02d", &year, &month)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%04d-%02d", year, month)
    }
}

The output is:

0024-02

I expected that Fscanf would fail since the year field isn't four characters long.
Is there a way to make Fscanf do what I want? If not, how should I parse this string?

I think your best bet is to prevalidate the string using a regular expression (package regexp):
var dateFormat = regexp.MustCompile(`^\d{4}-\d{2}$`)


if !dateFormat.MatchString(s) {
    ... complain ...
}

Demos: invalid case 24-02; valid case 2024-02. (Note that I've also taken the liberty of switching from bytes.NewReader + fmt.Fscanf to just fmt.Sscanf, which scans a string directly.)

This is what I ended up doing.


Is there a way to make Fscanf do what I want? If not, how should I parse this string?

You are trying to parse a date, then do proper date-time parsing using the time.Parse() function:
for _, s := range []string{
    "2024-02", // Good input
    "24-02",   // Bad input
} {
    t, err := time.Parse("2006-01", s)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("bad input:", err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%04d-%02d\n", t.Year(), t.Month())
    }
}

This will output (try it on the Go Playground):
2024-02
bad input: parsing time "24-02" as "2006-01": cannot parse "24-02" as "2006"

